# Kindle app takes up entire screen on windows 10 and I don't know how to get out of it

Tags: kindle, kindle-app, windows

I just downloaded the Kindle app for my Windows 10 PC. When I open a book, the app takes up the entire screen. I can't see any of my other apps, and I can't figure out how to close Kindle or switch to another app. If I hit ESC, it does nothing. The only way I can get out of the book is to hit the Windows key on my keyboard, but this doesn't seem like a useful solution.

Comment: Hi just googled this query and found this thread. After several attempts on a WIN 10 laptop running Kindle App I can exit full screen by right click anywhere on screen. Simple but elusive!ing

Answer (score 3):

If you're in full screen on Windows 10 and on a touchscreen device (2-in-1 devices) and detachable keyboard, you just touch the bottom middle of the page and a menu appears. Touch the X and you're out of full screen.

Answer (score 1):

This drove me nuts, too. Alt-tab will allow you to move away from the the Kindle screen, but it doesn't close it. If Kindle offers a direct keystroke to close the program, they're keeping it a secret. But here's how you can force close it: move your cursor over the "K" (for Kindle) in your Windows Task Bar. Right click and select "Close window". Adios Kindle.

Answer (score 1):

The Kindle app must think it's on a tablet, or it's a "tablet only" app for Win 10, so it will have no visible title bar or close/minimize/maximize buttons. There are 2 ways.

- Using your finger (if a touchscreen) or mouse, "grab" the top of the Kindle app window where the title bar would normally be, and drag the window down. The app will disappear and this will close the app.
- or hit  the Escape key. This should also exit the app.

In both cases you will likely return to your (what I call) "tablet desktop", which is different from the normal Windows desktop that has been in use for 20+ years.
The "tablet desktop" has link to many apps, but in the bottom left (on my PC anyway) it has a link to a normal desktop you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

For my installation of Win10 I can still use alt tab or the like if I'm using a full screen application.

Maybe that would work for you, did you get the application from the website or from the store?

Sometimes they differ.

Answer (score 0):

On my Win10 machine I just downloaded the kindle version amazon made for windows 7 because of all the issues I had with the version from the store. You could try using that in the future.
https://www.amazon.com/gp/kindle/pc/download

Answer (score 0):

Swipe from the right.  Click 'Settings', 'Control Panel'.  The ctrl panel should pop up as should a bar along the bottom.  Look for the Kindle app on the bar and close it like you would normally close a program by R clicking/holding it down.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at that too but figured out: It's F11! F11 toggles in and out of full screen. Jeez...

Comment: F11 worked for me. drops out of full screen to the main view.